# If $A$ is a nowhere dense subset of a topological space $X$, then $X\setminus A$ is dense in $X$.

Tags: general-topology

> If $A$ is a nowhere dense subset of a topological space $X$, then $X-A$ is
>   dense in $X$.

$(\overline{A})^\circ = \emptyset$ ($\because$ $A$ is nowhere dense).

We want to prove, $\overline{X-A}=X$

How can I prove for arbitrary topological space? Please help me. If you have short alternate solutions, please share with me.

Comment: That question is related to metric spaces. I want the proof in general topological space too.

Comment: What do you see on that proof that is not valid in general topological spaces?

Comment: It was a question given in NBHM PhD 2012 screening test. they have given in the answer key that statement true for arbitrary topological spaces.

Comment: Yes, inedd it's true for arbitrary topological spaces. Is that supposed to be an answer to my question?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Why don't you just follow the link that I provided and see if you understand the answer given there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X,\tau)$ an arbitary topological space and $A\subseteq X$ nonwere dense. For any open set $V$ in $X$ we have that $V\cap X\setminus A\neq\emptyset$ because $(\bar{A})^\circ$ is empty (This implies that $A$ not contains open sets). So, $X\setminus A$ is dense in the topology of $X$.